# Maven jaxws plugin - skip execution

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, maven-3

I'm using the JAX-WS maven plugin (org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin version 2.2) to generate classes from a bunch of WSDL files in my project, and as the WSDLs never really change I would like to disable this code generation by default, and only enable it for a particular maven profile I've created. The  element of this plugin supports a  element, but setting this to true seems to do nothing. Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a known bug, and is there something else I could do to avoid this code generation?

My plugin configuration looks like this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>

    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>import-wsdld</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <wsdlFiles>
            <wsdlFile>MyWSDL.wsdl</wsdlFile>
          </wsdlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
      <skip>true</skip>
      <packageName>com.my.package</packageName>
      <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
      <keep>true</keep>
      <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
      <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
      <verbose>false</verbose>
    </configuration>

    <!-- Necessary to revert back to 2.1.7 -->
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Many thanks,

Joseph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, just do it (I mean plugin declaration with all its stuff) in `<profile>` block. I wouldn't rely on some magic plugin-specific solutions. Just use what Maven offers out-of-the-box and create `<profile>` with your `<plugin>` stuff.

Comment: Perfect - I didn't realise you could put that stuff in the profile block!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation of the plugin](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html) it has not "skip" parameter which of course means it will not support. The best solution is to put that into a profile as mentioned before.